# What is a safe way to mock out a security service?

Tags: security, asp.net-core

Let's say my web app uses AWS Key Management Service to get keys for encryption but I don't want to use the service when I'm developing - I want to use a mock that returns hard-coded values. How does one swap out the code without opening the possibility that a hacker takes advantage of this on the live server? i.e. the hacker configures the app to use the useless version.

Here's an example code of registering a storage service based on a config value. This means that I can develop without needing an internet connection...

```
    c.RegisterType<IStorageOperations>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
        configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseMock:Storage") ?
            (IStorageOperations) new FileOperations() :
                new S3StorageService()));
```

Comment: That is a rather broad topic. Show some code to better clarify what it is you are referring to. This might end up being an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If the design is SOLID this should be a non-issue. So this leads me to believe that you may have a design issue that needs addressing.

Comment: What might that design issue be?

Comment: Wouldn't be able to say for sure without seeing code. It could be one or more of many possibilities.

Comment: I've added some example code.

Comment: This might be of some interest to you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Yes, but they could be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest thing to do is manually change the code. Although then the problem becomes remembering to change it back.